# Prevent Excel from reformatting scientific notation from VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Before you claim that this is a possible duplicate, hear me out.

I'm trying to write some code for my company to be able to parse data onto a server, and in order to do so, I need to use scientific notation.

I've already figured out how to convert a regular number to scientific notation using `Format()`, but my problem is that I need to have Excel display 0.0000e+00, not 0.00e+00

My code is extremely basic:

```
Sub ConvertScientific()
    Dim org, conv
    If IsNumeric(Range("a2").Value) = True Then
        org = Range("a2").Value
    Else
        MsgBox ("This is not a valid number!")
    End If
    conv = Format(org, "0.0000E+00")
    Range("b2").Value = conv
End Sub
```

Most of that is stuff that doesn't even need touching, but the problem I'm running into is that, even though I've defined the format to be `"0.0000e+00"`, it still ends up resulting in `0.00e+00` format.

This is extremely essential to my program, mostly because it's meant to run automatically without having a defined spreadsheet where the decimal value is set to 4 on some cells. I know that it is possible to have my desired format, but the only way I've been able to do it is by doing it manually.

Many thanks to anyone with advice.

EDIT:

I discovered that a possible way of reformatting is using the `Range().NumberFormat` property, but it seems silly to have two lines of code, where one should be sufficient. If anyone could explain why my code isn't working as I understand it should, please feel free to let me know for a 1+ and/or a valid answer.

Comment: Exactly as @Ron showed in his answer below... Your problem isn't that you didn't convert the number, you never **set the format in Excel** in your Sub, so it reverted it the normal format it already had....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to have Excel DISPLAY it as you describe, before entering conv into B2, you can format it either as scientific with four decimals, or as text; or you can precede conv with a single quote

Option 1

```
With [B2]
    .numberformat = "@"
    .value = conv
end with
```

Option 2

```
with [B2]
    .NumberFormat = "0.0000E+00"
    .Value = conv
end with
```

Option 3

```
[B2].Value = "'" & conv
```

**EDIT**:  Excel sees values that are numeric as numbers; it stores them in accord with the IEEE standard that it is using, and displays them pretty much as it sees fit.  That is what is happening with your entry.  In order to CONTROL how Excel displays a value, you have to either enter the value as text, or format the cell as you desire.